# sort svnadmin lslocks by date -- get the latest lock

Tags: bash, sorting, svn, hook

I am writing a hook script which should send an email to everyone as soon as someone has locked a file.

Therefore, I need the user who locked the file, the path to the file and the date and time the file was locked.

Is there any way to sort the output of `svnadmin lslocks` by the date created? It seems that `svnadmin lslocks` randomly sorts all locks in the given repository.

[EDIT]
Some sample output of `svnadmin lslocks /path/to/repository/`:

```
Pfad: /path/to/test/myfile.txt
UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:847dfw969-43a15-422fe-9caa5-d
Eigentümer: user3
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:18:52 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (0 Zeilen):


Pfad: /myfile.txt
UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:9397da59c-es1d9-45d1f-92eb-2b627ca6471079
Eigentümer: user3
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:12:51 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (0 Zeilen):


Pfad: /path/to/text.cpp
UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:bfb9bs5246-4a783-42321-83f9-1723c4871cee22
Eigentümer: user2
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:13:31 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (0 Zeilen):


Pfad: /path/to/my.java
UUID-Marke: opaselocksken:2b13s07-f06b-4s043b-aae12-6db205ee379f99
Eigentümer: user1
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 13:26:26 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (1 Zeile):
Ich locke jetzt!
```

When I execute `svnadmin lslocks /path/to/repository/` again, the output looks like this:

```
Pfad: /path/to/text.cpp
UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:bfb9bs5246-4a783-42321-83f9-1723c4871cee22
Eigentümer: user2
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:13:31 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (0 Zeilen):


Pfad: /path/to/my.java
UUID-Marke: opaselocksken:2b13s07-f06b-4s043b-aae12-6db205ee379f99
Eigentümer: user1
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 13:26:26 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (1 Zeile):
Ich locke jetzt!

Pfad: /path/to/test/myfile.txt
UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:847dfw969-43a15-422fe-9caa5-d
Eigentümer: user3
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:18:52 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (0 Zeilen):


Pfad: /myfile.txt
UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:9397da59c-es1d9-45d1f-92eb-2b627ca6471079
Eigentümer: user3
Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:12:51 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017)
Läuft ab: 
Kommentar (0 Zeilen):
```

Those blocks of at least six lines are randomly sorted. But I need the most recent block. The block can have a comment, the comment can be n lines long. After each block, there is a blank line.

Comment: Post some sample output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this awk solution:

```
svnadmin lslocks | awk '{ if ( $1 == "Pfad:" ) { cnt++ } arry[cnt]=arry[cnt]$0"\n";if ( $1 == "Erstellt:" ) { arry1[cnt]=mktime(gensub("[-:]"," ","g",$2" "$3))"-"cnt } } END { asort(arry1);split(arry1[cnt],arry2,"-");indx=arry2[2];printf "%s",arry[indx] }'
```

Take the output of "svnadmin lslocks" and build an array (arry) of each block with a counter (cnt) incremented each time the line with "Pfad" is encountered. At the same time we create another array (arry1) containing extracted dates along with the count separated by "-". The dates use the function mktime to get the seconds the epoch, after presenting the date and time correctly (removing : and -) At the end, we sort arry1 by the date and the last element will hold the cnt we can use to print the last block from arry.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work. It prints one block, but every time I execute this command it is a different block, not the latest one. The problem is, that `svnadmin lslocks` will randomly sort those blocks. So the first block could have been created before block x and vice versa.

Comment: I've amended to get the seconds since epoch and use this to sort the dates.

Comment: still does not work. same behavior as before. To make it easier for you I updated my question to a more specific sample output of `svnadmin lslocks`. I translated some works initially but maybe there is a problem with that.

Comment: OK another amendment has been made. With the change in language taken into account ;@)

Comment: thanks, that did the job! worked as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

setting $/ to empty string turns perl in paragraph mode

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN {$/=""}
    push @A, $_;
    END {
        print for sort{
            $a=~/^CREATED.*$/m;
            my $a1=$&;
            $b=~/^CREATED.*$/m;
            my $b1=$&;
            $a1 cmp $b1
        } @A
    }'
```

To reverse order in sort block: `$b1 cmp $a1`.

EDIT: Since the question was updated

```
svnadmin lslocks /path/to/repository/ | perl -ne '
    BEGIN {
        # set input record separator to turn on "paragraph" mode
        # records are delimited by more than 2 newlines (\n\n+)
        $/ = "";
    }
    # append record to array @A
    push @A, $_;
    END {
        # print records sorted by matched regex
        print for sort {
            $a =~ /^Erstellt:\K.*$/m;
            my $a1=$&;
            $b =~ /^Erstellt:\K.*$/m;
            my $b1=$&;
            $a1 cmp $b1
        } @A
    }'
```

To store output with bash to a variable, for example

```
    content=$( svnadmin ... | perl ... )
    echo "$content"
```

Otherwise to avoid using perl, only with GNU sed and sort, (if date is always the forth line `sort -k 4`)

```
svnadmin ... |
    sed -rz 's/\n\n+/\x1/g;s/\n/\x2/g;s/\x1/\n/g' |
    LC_ALL=C sort -t $'\x2' -k 4 |
    sed -rz 's/\n/\n\n/g;s/\x2/\n/g'
```

EDIT: to memorize only the highest date

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN {
        $/ = "";
    }
    /^Erstellt:\K.*$/m or next;
    my $record_date = $&;
    $record_date gt $highest or next;
    $highest = $record_date;
    $record = $_;
    END {
        print $record
    }'
```

Comment: not quite sure I would initiate a perl script inside a bash script. Also not quite sure how I handle those variables. I know nothing about perl. In the end I need to be able to store all those information in a variable in bash and then execute all this command in a tcl script. (I need tcl for telnet automation).

Comment: sed: I get the following error: sort: multi-character tab '$\\x2'

Comment: perl: it works, it sorts is ascending so that the latest block is the last one. However, there are no line breaks, like this: `Pfad: /myfile.txt UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:997da59c-sdfdsf565df-92e46445df79 Eigentümer: user2 Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:12:51 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017) Läuft ab: Kommentar (0 Zeilen): Pfad: /path/to/text.cpp UUID-Marke: opaquelocktoken:bfb9b246-4a68-r4231-8369-72cff841sees2 Eigentümer: user1 Erstellt: 2017-07-12 11:13:31 +0200 (Mi, 12. Jul 2017) Läuft ab: Kommentar (0 Zeilen):`

Comment: which OS are you using and can you check line endings '\n' and not '\r\n' for example

Comment: I am using Debian 3.16.39-1, also I only want to print the last block. I used `pop @A` at the end but this prints a random element of the array.

Comment: `@A = sort {..} @A;` but if you need only the last you can avoid sorting just memorize the line with the highest date

Comment: sorry, I don't know perl. Could you help out with that again?

Comment: thanks, the last one worked, but I think i am staying with the awk solution.

Answer (score 0):

[`svnadmin lslocks`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.lslocks.html) is not the tool to be used in the [post-lock hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-lock.html) script. What you actually look for is [`svnlook lock`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.lock.html). When you use `svnlook lock`, you don't need to process the lock information and you don't need to sort it.

Comment: The problem with `svnlook lock` is that you need to specify the exact path to the file that was locked. But this is exactly the information I need. I want to send an email that tells everybody which file was being locked right now and who made that lock and when. Since I only get the user and the repository as a parameter in a post-lock hook script, the only way I get to the information is by using `lslocks`.